# PowerShell Parse INF file

Tags: parsing, powershell, powershell-ise

I am trying to parse an INF; specifically, driver version from the file. I am new to PowerShell, so I've gotten only this far.

The file looks like this:

```
[Version]
Signature   = "$WINDOWS NT$"
Class       = Bluetooth
ClassGuid   = {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}
Provider    = %PROVIDER_NAME%
CatalogFile = ibtusb.cat
DriverVer=11/04/2014,17.1.1440.02
CatalogFile=ibtusb.cat
```

The second last line has the information I am looking for. I am trying to parse out just `17.1.1440.02`.

One file may contain multiple lines with `DriverVer=...`, but I am only interested in the first instance.

Right now I've the following script.

```
$path = "C:\FilePath\file.inf"
$driverVersoin = Select-String -Pattern "DriverVer" -path $path
$driverVersoin[0] # lists only first instance of 'DriverVer'
$driverVersoin    # lists all of the instances with 'DriverVer'
```

Output is:

```
Filepath\file.inf:7:DriverVer=11/04/2014,17.1.1440.02
```

But I am only looking for `17.1.1440.02`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your expression more specific and make the part you want to extract a capturing group.

```
$pattern = 'DriverVer\s*=\s*(?:\d+/\d+/\d+,)?(.*)'
Select-String -Pattern $pattern -Path $path |
  select -Expand Matches -First 1 |
  % { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

Regular expression breakdown:

- `DriverVer\s*=\s*` matches the string "DriverVer" followed by any amount of whitespace, an equals sign and again any amount of whitespace.
- `(?:\d+/\d+/\d+,)?` matches an optional date followed by a comma in a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`).
- `(.*)` matches the rest of the line, i.e. the version number you want to extract. The parentheses without the `?:` make it a capturing group.

Another option (if the version number is always preceded by a date) would be to just split the line at the comma and select the last field (index -1):

```
Get-Content $path |
  Where-Object { $_ -like 'DriverVer*' } |
  Select-Object -First 1 |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Split(',')[-1] }
```

Comment: Thank you, first version worked great. :) Just for better understanding, could you break down the second snippet?

Comment: @MoA I replaced aliases with full cmdlet names in the second snippet. That should make it obvious what each statement does.